# Why is the set of all smooth sections of a smooth vector bundle closed under addition?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle, where $E$ and $M$ can have nonempty boundaries. Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be smooth global sections of $E$. I want to show that $\sigma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ defined by $\sigma(p)=\sigma_1(p)+\sigma_2(p)$ is also smooth.

It suffices to show that $\sigma$ is smooth on an open neighborhood of each point $p$ in $M$. I can do that when $p$ is an interior point of $M$. Because then there is a smooth local trivialization $(U,\phi)$, where $p\in U\subseteq\operatorname{Int}M$ and $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathbb R^k$ is a diffeomorphism. Then $\sigma|_U$ is smooth because it is a composition of the smooth maps
\begin{equation}
U\xrightarrow{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)}\pi^{-1}(U)\times\pi^{-1}(U)\xrightarrow{\phi\times\phi}(U\times\mathbb R^k)\times(U\times\mathbb R^k)\xrightarrow{+}U\times\mathbb R^k\xrightarrow{\phi^{-1}}\pi^{-1}(U)\text{,}
\end{equation}
where $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)(p)=(\sigma_1(p),\sigma_2(p))$ and $+((q_1,v_1),(q_2,v_2))=(q_1,v_1+v_2)$. But if $p$ is a boundary point of $M$, then I cannot argue as above, since $\pi^{-1}(U)$ could have a nonempty boundary, so $\pi^{-1}(U)\times\pi^{-1}(U)$ does not make sense.

Comment: Why would $\pi^{-1}(U)\times\pi^{-1}(U)$ not make sense in this case?

Comment: @Thorgott Because according to the definition of a product manifold (in Lee's book), in order for the product $M_1\times\cdots\times M_k$ of smooth manifolds with boundary to make sense, all but one of $M_1,\ldots,M_k$ should have an empty boundary.

Comment: Ah, I get your concern. This will turn out to be a non-issue, try looking at the section on "Manifolds with corners" later in the book. Anyhow, a slight modification of this argument will also do. You have $\phi(\sigma_i(p))=(p,\psi_i(p))$ for $p\in U,i=1,2$ and some smooth functions $\psi_i\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$. Then $\psi_1+\psi_2$ is smooth, because addition on $\mathbb{R}^k$ is smooth and $p\mapsto(p,\psi_1(p)+\psi_2(p))$ is smooth, but post-composing that with $\phi^{-1}$ gives precisely $\sigma\vert_U$. The alternative argument in your answer is also correct.

Comment: @Thorgott Wow, I did not know there were furthur generalization than manifolds with boundary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle. If $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth local trivialization and $\tau:U\to\pi^{-1}(U)$ is a rough local section of $\pi$, then
\begin{equation}
\phi\circ\tau(p)=(p,\tau^1(p),\ldots,\tau^k(p))
\end{equation}
for some functions $\tau^i:U\to\mathbb R$. $\tau$ is smooth if and only if each $\tau^i$ is smooth.

In my case, $\sigma^i=\sigma_1^i+\sigma_2^i$. Since $\sigma_1^i$ and $\sigma_2^i$ are smooth, $\sigma^i$ are
also smooth. Thus $\sigma$ is smooth.

I would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: Seems right to me. Basically we're sweeping concerns about smoothness at the boundary under the rug by using the definition in terms of coordinate functions. It was probably shown earlier in your text that this notion of smoothness at the boundary really is the right one.

Comment: @Charles Thanks!